# How to force load a page in plugin?

Tags: plugins, pages, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a plugin which do very simple task...

```
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] === '/foo' )
{
   // How to display the content of page of ID = 3, without using wp_redirect()
}
```

So the url is staying at `/foo`, but show the content of page ID = 3

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If `/foo` doesn't exist as a page, you can map the URI to another page with a rewrite rule:

```
function wpa_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'foo/?$',
        'index.php?page_id=3',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Seems that I need to flush the rewrite rule after adding it?

Comment: @Yoga - yes, see the plugin example on [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) to flush on plugin activation.